# Toggling Fn-Lock key without the keyboard [Windows]

Tags: windows, laptop, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, water-damage

I recently poured water on my laptop (Huawei Matebook)'s keyboard and it left it mostly intact with one, unignorable detail: Whenever I enable Fn lock, the entire keyboard stops working. I can't disable it again because it's not working. Sometimes, with sheer luck of smashing random buttons for hours or days, I manage to unlock Fn lock and everything works perfectly again until I accidentally hit Fn lock again.

How can I toggle Fn lock off software-side? And could I also prevent it from being toggled in the first place? I'm on Windows.

Pretty sure the Fn lock state is stored software-side and not in the keyboard itself, because I can boot into the BIOS, the Fn lock light turns off and the keyboard works fine again, until I enter Windows again.

Comment: It may be in Software - I cannot see that for my machine. I have this toggle stored in BIOS.  The only practical repair is to replace the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

The Fn key is usually treated by the firmware of the keyboard,
at a level below that of the operating system.

If the BIOS does not contain such an option, the keyboard needs to
be replaced.